# How to include and use a own class (from a plugin) into codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to use a class from a plugin into my codeigniter and there into my controller and modells

This is a part from the class i want to include and use

```
<?php 
//start of https://github.com/repat/plentymarkets-rest-client
namespace repat\PlentymarketsRestClient;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Stringy\Stringy as s;

Class PlentymarketsRestClient extends CI_Controller{

    const PATH_LOGIN = 'rest/login';
    const METHOD_GET = 'GET';
    const METHOD_POST = 'POST';
    const METHOD_PUT = 'PUT';
    const METHOD_PATCH = 'PATCH';
    const METHOD_DELETE = 'DELETE';

    const THROTTLING_PREFIX_LONG_PERIOD = 'X-Plenty-Global-Long-Period';
    const THROTTLING_PREFIX_SHORT_PERIOD = 'X-Plenty-Global-Short-Period';
    const THROTTLING_PREFIX_ROUTE = 'X-Plenty-Route';

    private $client;
    private $config;
    private $configFile;
    private $rateLimitingEnabled = true;
    private $throttledOnLastRequest = false;

    public function __construct($configFile, $config = null)
    {
        $this->client = new Client();
        if ($config !== null) {
            $this->config = $config;
        } else {
            $this->config =  $this->readConfigFile($configFile);
        }
        ....
```

How i can indlude and use this in my codeigniter project?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Inherit your own class with codeigniter/plugin class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways. here is a simple way. I added the following code to the front of the Controller trying to use it.

```
require_once APPPATH . 'controllers/PlentymarketsRestClien.php'; 

class Dashboard extends PlentymarketsRestClien {
....
}
```